# In plain Qt5 widget code, how can I paint with "additive" blending?

Tags: c++, qt5, qpainter, blending

In my widget I want to draw a highlight. Currently it simply is white dot with some **alpha**, but to be correct it should be rendered with **additive blending**. However I am having a hard time figuring out how to do this in **Qt5 widget code**.

Does anyone know how?

Here is my paintEvent():

```
void LightWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *){
    WWMETHODGATE();
    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.setPen(Qt::NoPen);
    painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
    QColor black("black");
    QColor white("white");
    painter.setBrush(black);
    int m=2,m2=m*2;
    int w=width()-1, h=height()-1;
    int w2=w/2;
    int h2=h/2;
    int dim=std::min(w,h)-m2-2;
    int a=dim/2,b=a*2;
    painter.drawEllipse(w2-a-m,h2-a-m,b+m2,b+m2);
    painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);

    painter.setBrush(on?color:color.darker(300));
    painter.drawEllipse(w2-a,h2-a,b,b);
    white.setAlpha(192);
    painter.setBrush(white);
    int hl=b/4;
    //This is the highlight
    painter.drawEllipse(w2+a/2-hl, h2-a/2-hl,hl*2,hl*2);
}
```

Comment: So you draw this in `paintEvent`? Showing relevant part of your current `paintEvent` would make answering easier (by showing modified version of your own code) and increase chances of getting an answer or upvotes..